# active user by month

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have the dataset like :

| user | active | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-02-20 |
| 1 | 0 | 2020-04-02 |
| 1 | 0 | 2020-06-01 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-08-24 |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-03-08 |
| 2 | 0 | 2020-04-01 |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-05-23 |
| 2 | 0 | 2020-06-07 |

Based on the dataset we are expected to check whether the user was active or not for every month starting his first activity. Example here in the dataset `user 1` got deactivated in `April 2020` and was inactive till `July end 2020` . So in this case , the result for the above dataset would look something like :

| user | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-02-29 |
| 1 | 2020-03-31 |
| 1 | 2020-08-31 |
| 1 | 2020-09-31 |
| . | .......... |
| 1 | 2021-01-31 |
| 2 | 2020-03-31 |
| 2 | 2020-05-31 |

Comment: How is the first user active on Feb 1 but not on Apr 1?  I don't get the rules.

Comment: Just edited the expected result , my bad !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to know if someone is active on the last day of each month.  If they are currently active, you want all months since they started to last month.

You can get the active/inactive periods using window functions.  Then you can use a recursive CTE to generate the months:

```
with recursive ud as (
      select t.*
      from (select t.*,
                   min(case when active = 0 then date end) over (partition by user order by date desc) as inactive_date
            from t
           ) t
      where active = 1
     ),
     cte as (
      select user, last_day(date) as dte, inactive_date
      from ud
      union all
      select user, last_day(dte + interval 1 month), inactive_date
      from cte 
      where last_day(dte + interval 1 month) < coalesce(inactive_date, curdate())
     )
select *
from cte
order by user, dte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7b3e7cb8adff8a95554c6e00fa4a6e22) is the db<>fiddle.